# Stripe client checkout & services

Tags: vue.js, symfony5, stripe-payments

So I am trying to use stripe checkout to allow customers to subscribe to a web-based software service. using the nodes package "vue-stripe-checkout".

However, when I try to redirect the user to the checkout it says my SKU is not valid (which I can not find on my dashboard). So I create a new SKU for every subscription.

When I try to use the PHP Stripe API it throws the following error

```
The product must be of type 'good', but a product of type 'service' was specified.
```

There does not seem to be a setting to change the products to goods as opposed to a server? Is this defined by how the pricing structure works (e.g. recurring billing)

My Vue component mostly follows the demo given at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe-checkout.

My PHP code is as follows for creating the SKU

```
public function getPriceSku(
    string $priceId
)
{
    $price = $this->stripe->prices->retrieve($priceId);
    
    $sku = $this->stripe->skus->create([
        'attributes' => [
        ],
        'price' => $price->unit_amount,
        'currency' => 'gbp',
        'inventory' => [
          'type' => 'infinite',
        ],
        'product' => $price->product,
    ]);

    dd($sku);
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing or a good start to finish guide that will be useful? Stripe's API seems to generic to help me with this.

Comment: I'm having the same error, but using C#.
Did you eventually figure out what the problem was?

Comment: If someone else needs this visit https://stripe.com/docs/orders & look for type: 'good'